# Why variable in class returns nil while dumping class returns everything?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm starting with development in iOS and I have weird problem with my class called `Package`:

[image: An error]

You see, `print(data)` returns my class (with all data), but when I'm trying use single variable, it returns nil. Why and how can I fix it?

```
import RealmSwift

class Package:Object {
    var name:String?
    var code:String?
    var api:String?
    var created_at:NSDate?
    var updated_at:NSDate?
    var progress:[PackageStep] = [PackageStep()]

}
```

I'm using Realm.io to storage databases, and `Packages` extends from `Object` from that library

Comment: Instead of forced `try!` implement a `do - catch` block and analyze the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your properties must be declared as `dynamic`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes):

> Realm model properties need the `dynamic var` attribute in order for
>   these properties to become accessors for the underlying database data.
>
> There are two exceptions to this: `List` and `RealmOptional` properties
>   cannot be declared as `dynamic` because generic properties cannot be
>   represented in the Objective-C runtime, which is used for dynamic
>   dispatch of dynamic properties, and should always be declared with
>   `let`.

Comment: This works, but in some variables (eg. `progress`) i'm getting error "property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in objective-c". How about it?

Comment: For Arrays use `List<ObjectName>`